# efficient renaming of variables in first-order formulae

Tags: performance, algorithm, variables, formula, substitution

**edit<sub>2</sub>:** Taking the hint that de Bruijn indices might be easier to work with, I've reformulated much of the internal representation of formulae to use a mixed de Bruijn representation *ala* Connor McBride's paper. This greatly simplified some algorithms regarding syntax that had to deal with α-equivalence, but made others more complicated. In any case, this means that free variables can be standardized apart and bound variables have canonical names represented by their binding distance. This isn't totally satisfactory, but it's at least a better start.

**edit<sub>1</sub>:** I realized the problem constraints aren't sufficient to guarantee standardization of variables. In particular, iteration of quantifiers means that variables in binders must be standardized apart first. So there is probably no escaping a solution that requires multiple passes over each abstract syntax tree. The suggestion to use de Bruijn indices is a fairly good solution generally, but it won't give standardization easily without breaking the notation and its utility.

**original:**
Let *V* be an infinite set of variables indexed by the natural numbers, *fv*(φ) denote the free variables of φ, and *bv*(φ) denote the bound variables of φ, for any first-order formula φ. The problem I'm trying to solve is the following.

> Let φ and ψ be first-order formulae. Find substitutions θ<sub>1</sub> and θ<sub>2</sub> such that: (a) *fv*(θ<sub>1</sub>(φ)), *fv*(θ<sub>2</sub>(φ)), *bv*(θ<sub>1</sub>(φ)), and *bv*(θ<sub>2</sub>(ψ)) are disjoint; (b) the union of *fv*(θ<sub>1</sub>(φ)), *fv*(θ<sub>2</sub>(φ)), *bv*(θ<sub>1</sub>(φ)), and *bv*(θ<sub>2</sub>(ψ)) is isomorphic to an initial segment of the natural numbers; and (c) all variables in *bv*(θ<sub>1</sub>(φ)) are less than all variables in *bv*(θ<sub>2</sub>(ψ)) are less than all variables in *fv*(θ<sub>1</sub>(ψ)) are less than all variables in *fv*(θ<sub>2</sub>(ψ)).

The difficulty is that the set of bound and free variables in a formula isn't necessarily disjoint, and quantifiers may be iterated, meaning that naive substitution produces accidental variable capture, and so forth.

An inefficient solution is the following. Given φ and ψ, first standardize apart the free variables of φ and ψ such that all free variables in the standardized terms are greater than the largest bound variable plus the number of binding operators in φ and ψ, giving φ' and ψ'. Then rename the bound variables of φ' starting from x<sub>0</sub>. Then the bound variables of ψ'. Then the free variables of φ'. Then the free variables of ψ'.

What I would like is a more efficient method of satisfying the problem constraints. That is, a solution that doesn't require the initial standardization that renames free variables. Standardizing variables apart efficiently isn't a problem. However, the additional constraint is giving me trouble.

Comment: How are you representing such formulas? Which programming languages are you using? Do you have easy access to quantifiers, subformulas, terms, variables, operators? Or do you have just a string?

Comment: what's 'initial segment of ω'? The only ω I can recall (apart angular quantities and the like) relates to Cantor' set.

Comment: The formulae are represented as algebraic data types, meaning that I have access to their abstract syntax tree. The problem is more general than my implementation, however. Ideally, a solution would just be an operation or set of operations on the abstract syntax trees of two formulae.

Comment: @chac: I edited the post to make it more clear, changing "...initial segment of ω" to "...initial segment of the natural numbers" - i.e, if there are *n* variables in the set then the first variable has index 0 and the last has index *n* - 1.

Comment: Have you considered represening variables with their De Bruijn idices?

Comment: de Bruijn indices don't really work in this situation, because the problem is standardizing the variables in two formulae apart using a canonical renaming of variables having the indicated properties. Representing bound variables as distances from their binders doesn't really permit this.

Comment: You're not explaining how you chose the constraints on variable naming. In particular, why should it matter how bound variables are named, since any recursive algorithm on a formula (eg applying a substitution) would be able to determine that a variable is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use De Bruijn idices for sure. Also, notice that they all positive. Then you can use the negative numbers during the unification process. If you want to use fresh indices, use a global one.